# django relation between classes

Tags: django, django-models

Let say you have a class Project that is own by a team. One team can have many projects, but only one team for each project.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_manager = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=CASCADE)

    title           = models.CharField(max_length=55, null=True, blank=True)
    developers      = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='projects')
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)
    description     = models.TextField(default="Project description")
    teams           = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=CASCADE)
    tasks = project.task_set.all()   <-- like this?
```

Then each project has a task, so have to create a task class with a foregin key to project

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=55, null=True, blank=True)
    members         = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='tasks')
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, blank=True)
    task_completed  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    description     = models.TextField(default="Task description")
    project         = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

when then trying to get all the members from the task class, while being in a view for the project class, there is no relation, project does not have access, how do one make sure project knows of Tasks as Tasks knows of project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your tasks with [`_set.all()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

To access to your tasks based upon the project :

`tasks = project.task_set.all()`

Comment: updated, was that how you ment?